# Google - "Migrate to the new Google Identity Services library as soon as possible". Do we need to remove our use of google-api-php-client?

Tags: php, google-signin, google-api-php-client, google-api-js-client, google-identity

I received an email from Google stating that 'One or more of your web applications uses the legacy Google Sign-In JavaScript library. Please migrate your project(s) to the new Google Identity Services SDK before March 31, 2023.'

This is a surprise, as we recently upgraded to using only the https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client library for logging the user in. I have no mention of the old API (gapi) in my source code.

I'm using the oauth endpoints directly to query the API.

I'm worried that I will need to stop using the PHP library now as well. Can anybody please offer some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google apis php client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) is a library designed to use Oauth2 to access google apis.  It uses the PHP scripting language

The [Google Sign-In JavaScript library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) is a JavaScript library used for Signing in users to your application using their google account.

First off Oauth2 is not sign in.  Second Php scripting language is not the JavaScript scripting language.

These are two different things. The php client library has nothing to do with gapi which is part of the JavaScript client library.

I would check the rest of your system to ensure that you are not using the JavaScript library.  Your php library is unaffected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm definitely not using the JavaScript library, I'm only using the PHP library. The question is, is the PHP library also being deprecated?

Comment: I can assure you that the [Google apis PHP client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) is **NOT** being deprecated.  If you read the message it clearly states *Google Sign-In JavaScript library* If you are not using this library then you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you! To clarify: 1. There is no migration needed for querying the API directly with https://content-gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/ & https://content-gmail.googleapis.com/batch ? 2. Why would I get an email that says "migrate to the new Google Identity Services" via https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis if I don't even have gapi in my codebase?

Comment: Because Google doesn't know what developers are doing so they email everyone when there is a major breaking change.  It was just a warning mail, if you are using that.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I got the same mail from google, but I am using node js sdk for googleapis, do I have to do something for it?